# Set Quantity Limit in Shopware 6 Product

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have the following code with which I want to add the maximum quantity to the product. The product is also added but unfortunately the user can increase the quantity popular. Why is that?

```php
$lineItem = $this->factory->create([
    'type' => LineItem::PRODUCT_LINE_ITEM_TYPE,
    'referencedId' => $item->getId(),
], $context);

$qi = new QuantityInformation();
$qi->setMaxPurchase(4);

$lineItem->setQuantityInformation($qi);
$lineItem->setRemovable(true);
$lineItem->setQuantity($scgMainItem->getCount());
$lineItem->setStackable(false);
$lineItem->setLabel($item->get('translated')['name']);
$lineItem->addExtension('scgItem', new ArrayEntity([ "isAdded" => true, 'isVariant' => true, 'parentId' => $item->getParentId() ]));
$lineItem->setPriceDefinition(new QuantityPriceDefinition(0, new TaxRuleCollection(), 1))->setPrice(new CalculatedPrice(0, 0, new CalculatedTaxCollection(), new TaxRuleCollection()));
$lineItem->setPrice(new CalculatedPrice(0, 0, new CalculatedTaxCollection(), new TaxRuleCollection()));
```